# Windows Application gets hanged when using a background worker process

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, visual-studio, multithreading

In my application i am sending emails of bigger size (> 2.5 Mb). Now till the emails are being sent, the application is in hanged up state (mouse cursor is of busy state).

One of my friend suggested to use background worker that "could" display message something like "Please wait...Sending email". I have no idea as to how to use the background worker process. Please guide me

Or, if there is any other quicker/easier alternative, i would appreciate the inputs

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET or Winforms? (Your question has both tags.) It makes a difference, because a BackgroundWorker is usually not a suitable solution for a web application.

Comment: Did you search here for Background Worker? There are several other questions related to using them; one of them may provide a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want your UI to hang while waiting for long processes you **have** to use a thread. `BackgroundWorker` is a good implementation of this that provides hooks for you to use to report progress, allow the user to abort the process etc.

There are plenty of questions about the `BackgroundWorker` here on Stack Overflow or check the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

Comment: i am referring MSDN document and duplicating first sample code on my PC. I am not getting CancellationPending and Reportprogress. Am i missing any reference? FYI, i have added System.Threading, System.Windows.Forms and System.ComponentModel.

Comment: @Xor - search Stack Overflow (or use google with site:stackoverflow) for "backgroundworker". There are lots of questions on this topic. If you are still having problems post the code you have **as a new question** and explain what doesn't work. However, I'm sure all the information you need is already out there.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to use a separate *process* - you want to use a different *thread*.

The work of sending the email shouldn't be done in the UI thread, as that will prevent it from updating. However, you *may* want to disable parts of your UI while the email is being sent, depending on your app.

When it comes to doing the email work in the background, you could create a new thread explicitly, use the thread pool, or create a `BackgroundWorker`. You probably want to use `Control.Invoke` or `Control.BeginInvoke` to marshal a delegate invocation back to the UI thread when the email has been sent. Personally I would probably use a thread directly for this - it sounds like it'll take a reasonable time, and my guess is that you won't be able to report meaningful progress (which is the main task that `BackgroundWorker` makes easy). EDIT: As per comments, `BackgroundWorker` also marshals exceptions to the UI thread, which you may find useful.

So something like:

```
public void SendEmailButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Make any changes to the UI here to disable whatever you want
    new Thread(SendEmail).Start();
}

private void SendEmail()
{
    // Do the sending of the email here (this is in the non-UI thread)

    // Then afterwards, possibly in a finally block
    Action action = EmailSent;
    this.BeginInvoke(action);
}

private void EmailSent()
{
    // Back in the UI thread, do whatever you need to indicate
    // success/failure, re-enable disabled parts of the UI etc
}
```

Comment: Sending an email is not done in the background. In fact thats fine that if the email is going in the 'front of eyes'. What happens that when i click "Send" button, the application gets hanged up as sending attachments > 2.5 Mb takes time...

Comment: @Xor: It's done in the background as far as the UI thread is concerned. By all means disable the rest of the UI and put up a progress bar or something similar, but you *don't* want to do it in the UI thread.

Comment: Using the `BackgroundWorker` class has an additional advantage: Exceptions are caught and passed to the UI thread (in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event). With "manual" threads, some kind of catch-all exception handling is required in the background thread, otherwise it just stops and fails silently when an exception occurs.

Answer (score 1):

The [`BackgroundWorker` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) contains some pretty good examples which should help to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

A background worker is perfect for this.  It allows you to monitor progress quite easily and can Marshall back to the UI thread easier than a standard thread.  Some links after some google fu:

http://justins-fat-tire.blogspot.com/2010/05/c-using-background-worker.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use `BackgroundWorker` control. Refer below links

- [Designing an Interface for BackgroundWorker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848179/designing-an-interface-for-backgroundworker)
- http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx
- http://www.agiledeveloper.com/articles/BackgroundWorker.pdf

Comment: thanks for links. i am trying developing a demo (rather a duplicate) app from second link but i am not getting the 
_bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork; in first example. Am i missing something?

Comment: `_bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork`, `bw_DoWork` handler will be registered to the `DoWork` event of bw.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this threading tutorial:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Basic idea is to have your mouse click event spawn a new thread that will take care of sending the email.